# Getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute error when deploying pickle on Heroku but not localhost

Tags: python, python-2.7, heroku, pickle

When I deployed this project locally using `python server.py` I did not have this issue. I am currently loading a pickle file to get a variable that is an instance of a class Network. I originally had this problem with localhost, but I looked the problem up and the import statement for the class fixed it. Here's the relevant code for the problem:

```
import pickle
from network import Network
with open('network.pkl') as f:  
    net = pickle.load(f)
```

And here is the response I get when I tried to load it with Heroku:

```
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354034+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354035+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354037+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354038+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354040+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354041+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354043+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354044+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354045+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354047+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354048+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354050+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354051+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354053+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354054+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354056+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/server.py", line 12, in <module>
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354057+00:00 app[web.1]: net = pickle.load(f)
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354059+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1384, in load
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354060+00:00 app[web.1]: return Unpickler(file).load()
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354061+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354063+00:00 app[web.1]: dispatch[key](self)
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354064+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354066+00:00 app[web.1]: klass = self.find_class(module, name)
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354068+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1132, in find_class
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354069+00:00 app[web.1]: klass = getattr(mod, name)
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354071+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Network'
2019-08-15T13:55:36.354410+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-08-15 13:55:36 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-08-15T13:56:06.453204+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-08-15 13:56:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-08-15T13:56:06.453289+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-08-15 13:56:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-08-15T13:56:06.516449+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-08-15T13:56:06.501105+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
```

Thanks in advance.